# What's the relationship between FANS and CPDLC?

Tags: data-link

I'm confused about Future Air Navigation System (FANS) and Controller–pilot data link communications (CPDLC). Someone said FANS includes CPDLC, another said it does not.

Answer (score 4):

> *Someone said FANS includes CPDLC, another said it does not.*

It depends on the region and/or airplane generation.

There is the ICAO-compliant CPDLC used in Europe (via ATN-B1), and there is the Oceanic/US CPDLC (via ACARS).

- A plane fitted with FANS 1/A+ has the Oceanic/US CPDLC, but not the European one.
- New long-range planes like the 787 and A350 use FANS 2/B, which has both CPDLCs.$^a$

[image]

$^a$ This integration may be offered as a retrofit if it is possible. For example for Airbus – using Airbus' lingo – the A+B package was first introduced on the A350, then became available as a retrofit on the A380 *(see slide below by Airbus).*

[image]
(Airbus via [ICAO](https://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2012/DATALINK11/Sesion02%2006%20AIRBUS%20FANSSolutions.pdf))

---

For a brief historical context, see the history section I put together [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/44817/14897).