# What are the differences between FANS A, B, and C? Is FANS C commissioned?

Tags: navigation, data-link

For the Future Air Navigation System, what are the differences between FANS A, B, and C? Is FANS C commissioned?

Answer (score 3):

A, B, and C are the names used by Airbus. As a short summary:

- If you want text communication with ATC (CPDLC), you need FANS A in USA/oceanic, and FANS B or C in Europe.
- If you want position/trajectory reporting at set intervals (ADS-C) in continental Europe, then you need FANS C (still being tested).

> [image]
>   (Own work)

See the Airbus slide below for more:

> [image]
>   Source: Airbus via [icao.int](https://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2012/DATALINK11/Sesion02%2006%20AIRBUS%20FANSSolutions.pdf) (PDF)

Operational demonstration of FANS C started [a year ago in Europe](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/press-releases/en/2019/03/airbus-delivers-first-fansc-equipped-a320-to-easyjet.html).

Related:

- [How does ADS-C and FMS relate to FANS?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65838/14897)
- [What's the relationship between FANS and CPDLC?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/64624/14897)

---

Acronyms list:

> <sup>► A623: ARINC protocol defining a set of data
>   link applications (DCL, OCL, D-ATIS)
>   ► ACARS: Aircraft Communication and
>   Addressing Reporting System
>   ► ACR: Avionics Communication Router
>   ► ADS-C: Automatic Dependent Surveillance -
>   Contract
>   ► ADS-B: Automatic Dependent Surveillance -
>   Broadcast
>   ► AFN: ATS Facility Notification
>   ► AOC: Airline Operations Control
>   ► ATN: Aeronautical Telecommunication
>   Network
>   ► ATSU: Air Traffic Service Unit
>   ► CM: Context Management
>   ► CPDLC: Controller Pilot Data Link
>   Communication
>   ► CVR: Cockpit Voice Recorder
>   ► D-ATIS: Digital ATIS
>   ► DCL: Departure Clearance
>   ► DR: Data link Recording
>   ► FANS: Future Air Navigation System
>   ► FMS: Flight Management System
>   ► HFDL: HF Data Link
>   ► HFDR: HF Data Radio
>   ► IMA: Integrated Modular Avionics
>   ► LRU: Line Replaceable Unit
>   ► OCL: Oceanic Clearance
>   ► RMP: Radio Management Panel
>   ► SDU: Satellite Data Unit
>   ► VDL: VHF Data Link
>   ► VDR: VHF Data Radio</sup>